# Discard all outbound emails with exception of single subject using Postfix

Tags: postfix, regex

How do I discard all emails before they're sent with Postfix if they don't end with a certain string?

I've set up the below header_check regex but Postfix doesn't like it.

```
Sep 12 09:09:24 evolve postfix/cleanup[8857]: warning: regexp map /etc/postfix/header_checks, line 2: Invalid preceding regular expression
```

Regex I've done is:

```
/^Subject:.*((?!Change password confirmation).)*$/      DISCARD
```

The result should be that any email that doesn't end in the string "Change password confirmation" should fail.